# RadAjaxManager won't allow me to Rebind my RadTreeList

Tags: telerik, radajaxmanager, telerik-ajax, radtreelist

I am using a RadTreeList to display items, a RadContextMenu (Insert, Update, Delete) for when right clicking on a Tree Item and a RadWindowManager to help open a popup window on RadContextMenu ItemClick. When they click Insert or Update a dialog window opens smoothly they save, the dialog closes, treelist rebinds perfectly. When they click Delete I do not need to open a Window just run the code for deleting and then RadTreeList.Rebind();

Rebind will not work because of this item in my RadAjaxManager. The reason it is in here is so the dialogs open smoothly when the context menu is clicked.

**The Ajax Setting messing things up, but also making my popups open smoothly:**

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rcMenu">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadWindowManager1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
    </UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

**Here is how I have my Context Menu setup:**

```
<telerik:RadContextMenu ID="rcMenu" runat="server" OnItemClick="rcMenu_ItemClick" EnableRoundedCorners="true" EnableShadows="true">
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Insert" Value="Insert"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Modify" Value="Edit"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Delete" Value="Delete"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
               </Items>
</telerik:RadContextMenu>

    <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" EnableShadow="true" VisibleOnPageLoad="true" EnableViewState="false">
    </telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

Does anyone know of any workarounds so I can get the smooth dialog openings for Insert and Update, and for delete the page will still rebind the treelist when I call RadTreeList.Rebind();?

Comment: You can call a rebind in javascript.  But i'm still not sure why the delete wouldnt work with what you have here.

Comment: The delete is happening. The rebind is not working unless I remove that AjaxSetting above. It is most likely because the order of operations is: Right click TreeListRow, click Delete in ContextMenu, goes into ContextMenu_ItemClick, since it is delete we are not opening a window so the AjaxSetting should be irrelevant, run the delete code, attempt to rebind treelist and I get nothing, no console errors.

Comment: So is it doing a full postback on the delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rcMenu">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadWindowManager1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadTreeList" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rcMenu" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" /> <%--Please remove this if not necessory--%>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Although I have one quick question about the RadAjaxManager. How come sometimes people will set an Ajax setting such as RadGrid1 and then also an AjaxUpdatedControl of RadGrid1 within it? Same as in the above example (I know you say to remove it if not necessary) but why would we want it in there in the first place? My guess is that it is a simple way to give a single control itself ajax functionality.

Comment: <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rcMenu"> This code line showing that in when any event fire at that some you have to update some controls in UI.  The controls which was defined in tag <UpdatedControls>. We are not performing any CRUD operation in Menu so no need to write menu control ID inside <UpdatedControls>. as per your requirement we are based on menu click we are updating radwindow and treelist so.